# Как переключить американский английский на британский английский в генераторе/синтезаторе речи в приложении, разрабытываемом в Андроид Студии?

Tags: android, android-studio, локализация, text-to-speech, android-text-to-speech

Вот это работает. Язык в генераторе речи на русский меняется:

```
 ...
 Locale locale = new Locale("ru");  
 result = mTts.setLanguage(locale);
 ...
```

А вот это ничего не помогает (акцент остается американский):

```
 ...
 ни Locale locale = new Locale("en");    result = mTts.setLanguage(locale); 
 ни Locale locale = new Locale("en_GB"); result = mTts.setLanguage(locale); 

 ни result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
 ни result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
 ...
```

Comment: в Android Studio есть какой то генератор речи? он вам набранный код зачитывает? Android Studio - редактор для набора кода, речь же в вопросе видимо идет о приложении, которое вы разрабатываете с ее помощью, да?

Comment: Скажите "Привет Android Studio, как переключить акцент речи" - там возможно есть встроенный помощник, но это не точно

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо! Подкорректировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, оказалось...

Дело не в Андроид Студии (хотя она, по идее, на стадии выполнения, должна была бы подсказать, что британский английский не хочет включаться!)...

Нужно в самом телефоне доустановить голоса (точнее: **голосовые данные**)

> Настройки > Язык и ввод > Синтез речи > Синтезатор речи Google >
>   Настройки > Установка голосовых данных > английский (Великобритания) > установить

И все ок. )

Comment: Спасибо @pavloff!